# Can I have two versions of Microsoft Access (2007 and 2013) installed at once so I can still open .adp files?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

We have Access 2007 at work and we're updating to 2013 which doesn't support .adp files anymore. My superiors doesn't want to convert the .adp files to something different. They want to have both 2007 and 2013 versions installed at once so they can open the .adp files in the 2007 version and anything else in the 2013 version.

Both versions are already kind of installed but when I open one of the files in the version I want (either by right clicking and choosing a program or making a shortcut and specifying the program in the "target" field) it opens the installation window and installs the version. Then I can open files in this version all I want but when I try the other version it installs again. Then the first version is uninstalled again so they keep overwriting themselves. So I can still have just one version installed at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two versions will be fighting continuously.

Your solution could be to install the [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) to run the ADP application:

[Microsoft Access Version Features and Differences Comparison Matrix](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/history/features.htm)

Comment: I tried it but the result is the same. They still install again when I open the other file even though it's Access Runtime

Comment: And you launch the ADP from a shortcut with the full path to the runtime?

Comment: I tried both the shortcut and setting the default program for that file type.

Comment: I tend to resort to virtual machines for side-by-side Office/Access installs.  They're a bit more to maintain, having another OS, but worth the stability in these cases, I tend to find.

Comment: Sadly, I have had your experience confirmed. Then, I guess, you are left with the option noted by @jleach or, to ease the burden on the workstations, to set up a _Terminal Server_ running the ADP application and only Access 2007/2010 runtime installed. Or, of course, to convince management to spend the cost to convert the ADP to an normal application.